# In java socket programming, is it necessary to run server program first before client program?

Tags: java, swing, sockets

I am building a remote desktop viewer app using swing. When I run server first and then client, the app is working fine.

But when I run client first and then server, the client gives exceptions as there is no listening server.

What should I do so that if I run client first and then server the connection should be successful and client should not give exceptions?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest: catch the exception and retry every x seconds until you can find the server, giving the user the possibility to cancel the wait.

Answer (score 2):

`ConnectException` is thrown when client tries to connect a server which is not started. Have a retry logic using

```
try{ 
   socket.connect(..) 
}catch(ConnectException ex)
{  }
```

within loop. Delay can be added between retry to free the CPU.